# Inverse of a piecewise continuous function.

Tags: calculus, inverse-function, piecewise-continuity

I am trying to find the inverse of a two dimensional map $f\left(\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)$, 
For example
$$
f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{cases} ax + by, &(x,y)\in D_1 \\ ax^3 + b x^4, & (x,y)\in D_2\end{cases}
$$

For this question we have $f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)$ is defined as

$$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{cases} F_{0}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}\right), &y<a \\ \big(1-s(y)\big)F_{0}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}\right) + s(y) F_{1}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}\right), &a<y<b \\ F_{1}\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}\right), & y>b\end{cases}$$

We know the inverses of $F_{0}$ and $F_{1}$.

The inverse of the map $f$ depends on the point $(x,y)$ we give, like for $y<a$, we will take the inverse of $f$ as the inverse of the map $F_{0}$ and if the $y$ value is greater than $b$, then we take the inverse of the map $T_{1}$. But when the $y$ value lies in between $a$ and $b$, then we take the inverse of $$\big(1-s(y)\big)F_{0}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}\right) + s(y) F_{1}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}\right),$$ which I am not sure how to calculate the inverse of seems like applying $(g.h)^{-1} = h^{-1}.g^{-1}$ will help in this case, still how to find the inverse of the piece o fthe function defined in $a<y<b$?

Comment: $s(y)F_0(v)$ is not a composite function. It is just a product. The rule you have mentioned is true for composite functions. I don't think products follow that rule.

Comment: This function doesn't have an inverse if $F_0(x,y) = F_1(u,v)$ for some $(x,y)$ with $y<a$ and $(u,v)$ with $v > b$.

Comment: @BalakrishnanRajan yup you are right!

Comment: @amsmath nice, but let us suppose this doesnot happen!

Answer (score 2):

A linear combination of invertible functions is not necessarily invertible. A very simple example is $f_1(x) = x$ and $f_2(x) = -x$. They are each invertible, actually being their own inverses, but $f(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x) = 0$ is not invertible.

In your case, invertibility will depend on what $$\big(1-s(y)\big)F_{0}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}\right) + s(y) F_{1}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$
results in, but even if this is invertible, you're not likely to find any easy formula to determine what it is from the base parts of $s$, $F_0$ and $F_1$.